Left shift vs Mask Uint8Array
I wanted to know if anyone knows what would be faster and why.
do:
this.data[byte] |= 1 << bitIndex;
Or do1:
const BIT_MASKS: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]);
this.data[byte] |= BIT_MASKS[bitIndex];

https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

BIT_MASK is generally slower than a bitwise op due array element access, no need to pre-cache:
` Chrome/125
------------------------------------------------
shift  ■ 1.00x | x1000000000 399 406 407 408 413
mask     1.12x | x1000000000 445 454 461 462 466
------------------------------------------------ `

Open in the playground


let num = 100, bitIndex = 1;

// @benchmark shift
num |= 1 << bitIndex;

// @benchmark mask
const BIT_MASKS = new Uint8Array([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]);
// @run
num |= BIT_MASKS[bitIndex];

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



